# View, compare, and copy SELinux configurations between machines?

Tags: redhat, httpd, selinux, jboss

I have two machines running the same JBoss and HTTPD setup. They started from the exact same install of RedHat 7 and the same process was followed to install everything on both machines.

On one machine, everything works perfectly fine with SELinux running with the default settings. I never touched SELinux on it.

On the other machine, when I try to access it in a web browser, I get 403 forbidden error messages. When I searched around online for why, I found a suggestion that I should disable SELinux on it and see if it works then. So I ran `setenforce 0`, restarted jboss and httpd, refreshed my browser, and the forbidden message went away, everything worked again. I flip SELinux back on with `setenforce 1`, restart the applications, refresh the browser, and the forbidden message is back.

So on my second machine, there definitely seems to somehow be something wrong with SELinux. It's weird, because I didn't touch SELinux on either machine until I tried turning it off on the second. I've verified that on the first machine, when I run `getenforce`, it does return `Enforcing`.

My question is - how can I view the SELinux configurations on each machine? How can I compare them, to find out where the differences are between them, and edit or copy them so that I can run SELinux on the second machine without interfering my apps, just like on my first machine?

**Edit** - I ran this command to search the audit logs:

```
cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep httpd | grep denied
```

The first line is repeated several times. The last two lines only showed up once at the very end.

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1468877854.297:22110): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=5193 comm="httpd" path="/var/www/html/sfo/index.htm" dev="dm-0" ino=70334613 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1468877854.297:22111): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=5193 comm="httpd" name="index.htm" dev="dm-0" ino=70334613 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1468877854.297:22111): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=5193 comm="httpd" path="/var/www/html/sfo/index.htm" dev="dm-0" ino=70334613 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
```

I don't see any similar messages on the machine where SELinux is running without improperly blocking the page. Both machines have the same permission flags set for /var, /var/www, /var/www/html, /var/www/html/sfo, and /var/www/html/sfo/index.htm

All the directories have `drwxr-xr-x`, the index.htm file has `-rw-r--r--`. All are owned by user root and group root. `md5sum` says /etc/sudoers are identical. Nothing is in /etc/sudoers.d on either machine.

Both machines have the same output for `getsebool -a | grep httpd`:

```
httpd_anon_write --> off
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on
httpd_can_check_spam --> off
httpd_can_connect_ftp --> off
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> off
httpd_can_connect_mythtv --> off
httpd_can_connect_zabbix --> off
httpd_can_network_connect --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off
httpd_can_network_memcache --> off
httpd_can_network_relay --> off
httpd_can_sendmail --> off
httpd_dbus_avahi --> off
httpd_dbus_sssd --> off
httpd_dontaudit_search_dirs --> off
httpd_enable_cgi --> on
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
httpd_enable_homedirs --> off
httpd_execmem --> off
httpd_graceful_shutdown --> on
httpd_manage_ipa --> off
httpd_mod_auth_ntlm_winbind --> off
httpd_mod_auth_pam --> off
httpd_read_user_content --> off
httpd_run_stickshift --> off
httpd_serve_cobbler_files --> off
httpd_setrlimit --> off
httpd_ssi_exec --> off
httpd_sys_script_anon_write --> off
httpd_tmp_exec --> off
httpd_tty_comm --> off
httpd_unified --> off
httpd_use_cifs --> off
httpd_use_fusefs --> off
httpd_use_gpg --> off
httpd_use_nfs --> off
httpd_use_openstack --> off
httpd_use_sasl --> off
httpd_verify_dns --> off
```

Comment: Compare outputs from `getsebool -a | grep httpd` ? Read SELinux logs to get clues : `/var/log/audit/audit.log` ? Exact same install may involve some directories copy which could have their own original SELinux context at source : try to restore default context `restorecon -r /var/www/html` (or anywhere is your www root dir)

Comment: @krisFR - I've updated my post with some contents from `audit.log` and `getsebool`. The output of `getsebool` is identical on both machines, but `audit.log` only mentions denying `httpd` access to anything on the machine where I get the forbidden error. The log line is pretty cryptic to me though - are you able to interpret it and tell me what's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Use `ls -Z` to see how the filesystem is currently labeled on both machines.

Comment: @bodgit - That does spit out different results on each machine... I'm completely unfamiliar with this command. On the machine where it works, `www` has this: `system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0`. On the machine where it doesn't, `www` has this: `unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0`. What does this mean? How do I make them the same? Is there some additional reading that I'm going to want to look at (in ~5 years of using bash, I've never seen this before...)?

Comment: It's an SELinux construct, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SELinux the filesystem has extra "permissions" above and beyond the regular UNIX ones. If you were to run `ls -Z ...` (`-Z` is an SELinux extension to `ls(1)`) on files under `/var/www/html` across both machines I suspect you will see the following:

On server A:

`drwxr-xr-x  root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/`

On server B:

`drwxr-xr-x  root root system_u:object_r:var_t          /var/www/html/`

etc.

On server A this *is* labelled correctly for Apache to read that directory with SELinux active. On server B the directory *isn't* labelled correctly for Apache to read it while SELinux is active.

In order to fix it, try first running `restorecon -Rvn /var/www/` which will show you how the filesystem would be changed to match the currently-running SELinux policy. If that looks sane, remove the `-n` flag and re-run.

There's also a helpful `httpd_selinux(8)` manpage that documents SELinux with regards to Apache.

Comment: Okay... so this would have happened because I tarred the `www` folder on A, SSH'd it over, deleted the existing `www` on B, then untarred to make the `www` folder on B? And tar only preserves the regular UNIX permissions, not SELinux's extra ones?

Comment: That would do it, however tar _does_ have support for handling extended ACL information including those of SELinux, see the manpage. A lot of core filesystem-related tools shipped with the base RHEL/CentOS system will often have extra SELinux options added.

Comment: Okay, yeah, in the man page for `tar` I do see a `--selinux` option, but I also see a `--no-selinux` option... which one would be the default? I could imagine it defaults to not including `--selinux` when writing (so it can be read on older machines) but defaults to checking for the presence of `--selinux` when reading? IDK. Not familiar enough with the tar format to know how future-proof it is.

Comment: If you're moving the archive between homogenous machines with an identical SELinux policy you can also do something like `tar zxvf foo.tar.gz | restorecon -f -` which doesn't require the archive to store the SELinux information.

Comment: One more question... on server A, it starts with `system_u`. On server B, even after running that `restorecon` command (and with everything working fine), it starts with `unconfined_u` instead. What's the difference? Should/can I make them the same?

Comment: I think with the default targeted policy it's mostly ignored so I wouldn't worry about it.